# Can i call method from .net console application under custom user?

Tags: .net

I have a console application and i would like to call method from it under another user. Can i specify this user and password in attribute to method?

Comment: It depends on what you define as "user" - the process will still be running as the same identity, but you can have a "principal" per thread, which is another representation of a user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

You can't have a single method run under a different user context.